# calculating the Strahler number (minimum # of registers) needed to evaluate an expression

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorics, cpu-registers, compiler-architecture

If I have an arbitrary expression consisting of primitive operations on registers, is there an easy way to calculate the [Strahler number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strahler_number) (minimum # of registers which must be allocated) for that calculation?

e.g. f(a,b,c,d) = a*b + c*d - a*c - b*d

I know how to do it by hand, but I'm trying to get a sense of how register allocation requirements correspond to particular sets of algorithms, and it would help to have a quick tool for calculating these numbers.

Comment: IIRC, register allocation is NP complete, therefore calculating Strahler number is probably also NP complete.

Comment: It's NP complete for non-SSA forms. And I'm not looking for an algorithm to allocate registers, just a measure of how many numbers need to be allocated. I've found some references on Strahler numbers but they get into depth-first searches and phrases like that which make my eyes glaze over.